# Object reference in vb. Net when clicking icon

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, icons

I have a panel that fills with icons of characters. I have a second panel I would like to fill with icons from which character is selected. What is the best way to know which character was selected? Both panels are flow layout panels. I can hover over the character and display the name but I need a good way to reference which character is clicked. The entire object is a user control and another object that retrieves the champion icons to fill the first panel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the form.KeyPress event.

[Control.KeyPress Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Examine the KeyEventArgs and go from there.